# Автоматическое изменение одной java переменной, при изменении другой

Tags: java, java-8

**Есть кусок кода**:

Объект random типа ArrayList содержит объекты Vector2 с двумя координатами x и y - new Vector2(x, y)

```
public void updateRestartPos() {
        // Случайно перетасовываем список random
        Collections.shuffle(random);

        // Приравниваем restartPos к первому элементу списка random
        restartPos = random.get(0);

        // Изменяем restartPos
        restartPos.x += 1;

        // Соответствующий элемент random(в данном случае первый)
        // также изменяется

        /* Some code */

    }
```

Почему при присваивании значения элемента списка random другой переменной и последующем ее изменении, изменяется также и соответствующий элемент random?

Answer (score 2):

Потому что переменная **restartPos** это просто ссылка, который смотрит на тот же объект коллекции с индексом 0.

Пример с clone():

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        MyObj myObj1 = new MyObj();

        MyObj myObj2 = (MyObj) myObj1.clone();

        myObj1.a = 10;
        myObj2.a = 20;

        System.out.println(myObj1.a);
        System.out.println(myObj2.a);
    }
}

class MyObj implements Cloneable {

    int a;

    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
}
```

Comment: Как тогда произвести манипуляции с нужным значением элемента списка, не изменяя его?

Comment: Тогда нужно создать копию этого объекта, в идеале это можно сделать с помощью метода clone(), но это не всегда хороший подход.

Comment: Если это не хороший, то тогда какой хороший? И вы не могли бы пожалуйста привести пример использование метода clone() ?

Comment: Я в текстовом редакторе в одиночном файле создаю список, присваиваю другой переменной его элемент, изменяю переменную, а список не изменяется

Comment: Посмотрите пример выше.

Comment: ArrayList list = (ArrayList<Vector2>)random.clone();
Vector2 restartPos = list.get(0);                     В данном примере объект list.get(0) имеет тип java.lang.Object, несмотря на то, что я выполнял функцию clone() с объекта списка, у которого элементы - Vector2. Не знаете почему так?

Comment: Слева забыли ставить дженерик <Vector2>

Comment: Точно, спасибо, сейчас проверю у себя в проекте как работает

Comment: Чего-то по прежнему при изменении переменной, изменяется сoответствующий элемент списка random(

Comment: Потому что вы клонировали сам список, надо клонировать объекты Vector

Comment: Пишет, clone() has protected access in java.lang.Object       Писал Vector2 v = (Vector2)((Vector2)random.get(0)).clone();

Comment: да надо переопределить метод clone(), как я написал вверху. и сделать его public. и да реализовать интерфейс Cloneable.

Comment: Спасибо за оказанную помощь, буду разбираться

Answer (score 1):

Приравнивая restartPos к random.get(0), мы получаем в restartPos ссылку на тот же самый random.get(0). Соответственно, при изменении restartPos изменяется и random.get(0).

Проблема была решена с помощью приравнивание не целого объекта типа Vector2 random.get(0), а его двух составляющих в отдельности: координат x и y - простейших(не ссылочных) типов int:

```
public void updateRestartPos() {
        // Случайно перетасовываем список random
        Collections.shuffle(random);

        // Приравниваем restartPos к первому элементу списка random
        // указывая по отдельности две его составляющие и создавая новый объект
        Vector2 vector = new Vector2(random.get(0).x, random.get(0).y);
        restartPos = vector;

        // Изменяем restartPos
        restartPos.x += 1;

        // Соответствующий элемент random(в данном случае первый)
        // не изменился

        /* Some code */

    }
```